# Small projector for affixing to a robot

Tags: linux, projector

I'm heading a research project in my robotics lab, and I'm looking for a small projector to affix to the top support structure of a [LoCoBot](http://www.locobot.org/). My plan is to have data/videos/images fed to the projector via the robot's local machine, so either HDMI or USB connection would work great. It would need to have a relatively small profile to fit comfortably on top of the robot's support structure, so something less than 7"x4"x5" (lxwxh). Weight is not as critical and will likely be constrained by the dimensions. One that can be charged would be great, but there is also a battery on the robot to power the robot, so it could also be powered via USB from the battery or the robot's machine. The battery has four unused USB slots - two providing 2.1A and two providing 1.0A.
Preferred resolution is XGA (1024x768 pixels, 4:3 aspect ratio).

The projector doesn't need to have a super far projection reach, <= 20 ft or so. Tripod threading would be a plus. The robot is running Ubuntu 16.04, so the projector would need to be compatible with Linux. I wasn't able to find many examples online of using projectors with [ROS](https://www.ros.org/), but if anyone knows of any projects or projectors that have been used, that would be helpful!

The project is still in its workshopping phase, and I'm admittedly not much of a projector expert. Unless there exists a type of automatic or remote focusing I can do remotely by ssh-ing into the machine, we would likely have to manually focus the projection. I'm not sure what additional info about the PC would be helpful, let me know and I'll edit the post to provide that info.

Comment: 1) How are you going to focus the image? Projectors need to be focused. 2) How heavy can the projector be? 3) How much current can you provide from the robot's battery? 4) What resolution do you want? Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: *"so the projector would need to be compatible with Linux"* -- Look for an HDMI projector. Many monitors/projectors support commands over HDMI in an OS-independent protocol like DDC or CEC. Meanwhile a USB projector would be both OS/driver dependant and probably lower resolution/framerate anyways.

Answer (score 0):

An [AAXA P2-B LED DLP Mini Cube Projector](https://smile.amazon.com/AAXA-P2-B-LED-Projector-Smartphone/dp/B075N25DS7/ref=pd_di_sccai_3/133-4969846-5887951?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B075N25DS7&pd_rd_r=81b49ad0-f45d-469d-976b-3c0b93081992&pd_rd_w=ahsLF&pd_rd_wg=TlbHU&pf_rd_p=61ce50cf-2379-4458-9044-fa8b402c702d&pf_rd_r=RAQ4MN570NGZCHC4T39E&psc=1&refRID=RAQ4MN570NGZCHC4T39E) is 3"x3"x2", weighs 12 ounces, has a tripod screw socket, has its own battery, recharges at 2A/5VDC, and will project a 130 lumen image of (diagonal) 150 inches or less (the smaller, the brighter). Its native resolution is 854x480 so you would need to verify your onboard PC can deliver that resolution of [Senators from Alderaan](https://images.app.goo.gl/1AgxjQCwhcShcPnB8) and other images, but it does have a mini-HDMI port for compatibility.